# How to do an array of timers in java

Tags: java, timer

I know I am probably way off here, but I am trying to create a timer array so that mytimer[0] mytimer[1], mytimer[2], etc... all fire off at a different interval, with diffrerent events sent to a server. Any ideas? The for loop value of 6 is an organic number for testing purposes only. This number would later be decided base on a setting from the program's xml file.

```
Timer mytimers[] = new Timer[6]; 
for(int i = 0;i < 6;i++){
    final int mytime = i;
    mytimers[i].scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do action
            sendData("Timer " + mytime + " fired");              
        }
    }, 10000, i*1000);
}
```

Comment: it throws: [ERROR]: java.lang.NullPointerException  on me when I run it from the netbeans ide.

Comment: Does the first line even compile? Where is the array in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Timer mytimers[] = new Timer();
```

I'm assuming this is the line that doesn't work? You can't initialize an array with an object; initialize it with an array:

```
Timer mytimers[] = new Timer[6];
```

Making another guess, you're also not initializing the individual timers:

```
mytimers[i].scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
```

At this point mytimers[i] isn't set to anything, so how can you call `scheduleAtFixedRate` on it? Initialize it first:

```
mytimers[i] = new Timer();
mytimers[i].scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
```

EDIT:

Your "IllegalArgumentException: Non-positive period." is because on the first time through the loop, `i = 0`, so `i * 1000 = 0`, and the period can't be 0 ("run this event every 0 zero seconds").

Start with `i = 1` and it should be fine.

Comment: How could that line possibly compile?

Comment: I know.  I'm agreeing and stating disbelief that the OP's code could possibly compile or run.

Comment: correct...I copied and pasted the wrong line there. I have
        Timer mytimers[] = new Timer[6];

Which compiles without errors, but throws the above mention error in the Netbeans IDE output window

Comment: @user1305988 - Please copy and paste your *exact* code into the question.

Comment: ok, so I made them changes and now i get a new error in the IDE output window: [ERROR]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-positive period.

Comment: @user1305988 - It's because your first argument to period is `i * 1000`, where `i = 0`, so period = 0, and you can't do that.

Comment: that would make sense. almost as bad as dividing by zero

Comment: Thanks for the help Brendan and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just doing one timer, and the putting all the different events in some sort of `(if timeElapsed % timerinterval[1] == 0)` and then that way you can simulate the different times by using just one timer.   Then you only need an array of integers with the timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Timer mytimers[] = new Timer[6]; 
for(int i = 0;i < 6;i++){
    mytimers[i] = new Timer();
    final int mytime = i;
    mytimers[i].scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do action
            sendData("Timer " + mytime + " fired");              
        }
    }, 10000, i*1000);
}
```

The problem is, you are calling the Timer() constructor on an array and never initializing your individual timers.  Rather, you should initialize the array *as an array* and the individual timers *as timers*.